# Curl only uses specified OpenVPN interface if ran as root

Tags: openvpn, curl

I am using Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver). I run OpenVPN with redirect-gateway disabled because I don't want traffic to use it by default, only one specific application. This is the command i use:

```
sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/CA\ Montreal.ovpn --pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway --daemon
```

And then if I use the following command:

```
curl http://ipinfo.io/ip --interface tun0
```

I get my real external IP address, not my VPN address. But if I run the command:

```
sudo curl http://ipinfo.io/ip --interface tun0
```

I then get my VPN IP address. I am experiencing this issue in other programs too, such as traceroute.

```
$ traceroute 1.1.1.1 -i tun0
traceroute to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
setsockopt SO_BINDTODEVICE: Operation not permitted
$ sudo traceroute 1.1.1.1 -i tun0
traceroute to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.21.10.1 (10.21.10.1)  73.600 ms  74.061 ms  74.045 ms
 2  199.229.249.253 (199.229.249.253)  74.041 ms 199.229.249.254 (199.229.249.254)  74.193 ms 199.229.249.253 (199.229.249.253)  73.995 ms
 3  199.229.249.6 (199.229.249.6)  73.991 ms  74.143 ms 199.229.249.2 (199.229.249.2)  74.021 ms
 4  ae7-67.cr0-mtl1.ip4.gtt.net (98.124.173.249)  74.065 ms ae7-103.cr0-mtl1.ip4.gtt.net (98.124.173.101)  74.113 ms  74.162 ms
 5  cloudflare-gw.cr0-mtl1.ip4.gtt.net (69.174.23.50)  74.210 ms  74.157 ms  74.384 ms
 6  one.one.one.one (1.1.1.1)  74.052 ms  73.802 ms  73.843 ms
```

How do I fix it so a program doesn't need root to go through the VPN?

Comment: Well...I just rebooted the server and now curl and traceroute don't work  at all. As either a user or root.